# Visual studio c++ на MacOs

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, macos

хотел бы прояснить, что я в курсе, что официально невозможно поставить с++ на VS for Mac, но надеюсь, что вы мне подскажите обходные пути, просто уж очень не хочется перестраиваться под интерфейс CLion, XCode и т.д. Я пробовал сделать это через CrossOver, скачивая именно Visual c++, но все бестолку, потому что так и не понял как соединить эту утилиту с VS.
Через виртуальную машину очень неудобно, потому что она очень медленная и кривая.
Если хотите сказать, чтобы тогда покупал бы Винду, не надо.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы использовать VS хотя бы как блокнот для кода на c++ и как отладчик, если это возможно все таки.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хе, надо было об этом думать, когда привыкали VS. Я бы сейчас один раз переучился (на vscode+clangd, например).

Comment: xcode хорошая вещь, единственная где есть человеческое определение утечки памяти